# I have two files xml, and I need to extract data from first xml file and insert in to second xml file

Tags: xml, bash, extract

I have two files xml, and I need to extract data from first xml file and insert in to second xml file.

first file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ITEMS>
<EVENT>
<codpal>8387</codpal>
<programming>ProgramName</programming>
<idCategory>28</idCategory>
<date>2011-07-16 17:00:00</date>
</EVENT>
</ITEMS>
```

Second File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ITEMS>
<EVENT>
<sign codice="xxxx" pro="xxxxxxxxxxx" id="xxx" data="xxxx xxx xxxx xx"  />
</EVENT>
</ITEMS>
```

Can anyone help me? the first file change any 20 min. And I need create a bash script to automate this export.

Comment: Stuart H is rigth. A solution using a real xml parser would be better. Personnaly I would check [xmlstar](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). I dont know the tool but its supposed to help you parsing xml from command line scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to write an XSLT to transform this if that is an option. This would avoid parsing mistakes/irregularities and make it more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

I would strip the html tags and empty lines, then put the result in an array:

```
values=(`sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' /tmp/xml | sed '/^$/d'`)
echo ${values[0]}
```

You should be able to get your values easily and produce the expected output using echo.

**Update:** There is a problem whit fields containing spaces. You may try to read line by line using this pattern:

```
while read line; 
do 
  echo $line; 
done < <( sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' /tmp/xml | sed '/^$/d')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use XQuery. It feels much clearer than XSLT. For example with my own [XQuery interpreter](http://videlibri.de/xidel.html) (which sadly cannot update the file directly):

```
xidel --xml file2.xml --xquery '<ITEMS>{ITEMS/EVENT, doc("file1.xml")/ITEMS/EVENT/<EVENT><sign codice="{codpal}" pro="{programming}" id="{idCategory}" data="{date}"  /></EVENT>}</ITEMS>' > file2.new.xml
mv file2.new.xml file2.xml
```